# calling function using own header file in C

Tags: c, assembly, project, header-files

I'm new to this site & not highly experienced in C,so pl pardon any mistakes I might commit unknowingly.
Ok,so I've got two files in C, one containing a function, & other one using that function.I think I'll need to create a header file for it,but I somehow cannot make it & need help. 
here's file 1 :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int tempc=25,tempf;
int c2f(int c);
void main()
{ 
tempf=c2f(tempc);
printf("Celsius = %d,Farenheit=%d \n",tempc,tempf);
}
int c2f(int c)
{
int f;
f=9*c/5 + 32;
return f;
}
```

Here's file 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int tempc=25,tempf;
extern int c2f(int c);
void extern show(void);
void main()
{
tempf=c2f(tempc);
show(); 
}
```

The main question comes here. you might as well be thinking about the show function.
Actually, I'm asked to convert f1 into .asm file (using tcc -S f1.c) then add a module for show fn using assembly language, create .obj file of the .asm file, & with .obj file of f2, I've to put them in project & then build all to create .exe file.But I believe if I can simply run the program using 2 files as .c(ie with header part solved) I can do the rest.
One last question is, instead of creating header I'm wanting to do above, is it possible to keep these two files as they are, & create a header file-> make it .obj & add it to the project & build ?

A Sincere thanks to whoever tries to help.

Comment: It seems to me that file 1 is your specification. Now you need to write some assembly that when linked to file 2 makes it work like your specification. In other words, this has nothing to do with header files.

Comment: ***`int`*** `main()`... (and indent your code, use whitespace, etc. your code is hard to read as-is.)

Comment: I might be thinking that, but i'm not. I'm thinking "Why does this guy's program have two `main()` functions, neither declared correctly?"

Comment: The int main() is not what is causing his problems.

Comment: Hi Sumedh and welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be really nice if you could write proper English without abbreviations and replacements such as an ampersand for and. Such things make it much more difficult especially for the large part of the Stackoverflow community that does not speak English natively to understand your question.

Comment: @FUZxxl,I'll keep that in mind. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A header file is meant to be used as a mechanism to "expose" functions to other C modules. For instance, you define a c2f() function in c2f.c and then create a prototype (essentially just a placeholder) in c2f.h. The prototype in c2f.h would look like the following:

```
int c2f(int c);  /* Note the semicolon */
```

It shouldn't matter if the implementation of c2f() is in an assembly or c file. The header file simply allows C modules to make calls to c2f(). This is because you are providing the linker information to find the actual implementation of a function. The linker will then match all calls to that function to the actual address of the implementation. So, to use c2f just reference c2f.h in the file that is using it:

```
/* main.c */
#include "c2f.h"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `c2f` in a header and source files as such:

c2f.h:

```
int c2f(int c);
```

c2f.c:

```
int c2f(int c) {
    return 9*c/5 + 32;
}
```

then compile that so you have a `c2f.o` file, include `c2f.h` in your two `main()` files that use it and linktheir compilation to the `c2f.o` file.

Comment: ok, so I made c2f.h & put it in INCLUDE,c2f.o in LIB 
& then compiled. no error in compiling.
but when I run f2.c it says: 
    linker error: undefined symbol _show in f2.c  
    linker error: undefined symbol _c2f in f2.c